# How would I change this method to work with an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void critReactRoomStateChange(String command, PC pc, String name) {
    Creature temp = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
        if (!(getCreatures()[i] instanceof PC) && !(getCreatures()[i].getName().equals(name))) {
            temp = getCreatures()[i];
            if (temp != null) {
                getCreatures()[i].reactStateChange(command, pc);
                temp.checkNewRoom();
                if (!temp.equals(getCreatures()[i])) {
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I switched from having a 
private Creature[] creatures;
array
to having a

```
private ArrayList<Creature> critArr = new ArrayList<Creature>();
```

ArrayList

I have changed the getCreatures() method to 
    public ArrayList getCreatures() {
        return this.critArr;
    }

The count will not be needed as that is just critArr.size().

If more details are needed please let me know.
Basic structure of my program 
Room Class 
  -holds creatures 
Creature Class 
  -defines creatures

so pretty much a Room can have Creatures in it.  I have multiple rooms that are set up and connected to each other through a simple interface of north, east, west, south.  Not needed information, but this allows you to understand the point.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With collections, it is generally good practise to make use of the enhanced for loop.

```
public void critReactRoomStateChange(String command, PC pc, String name) {
    List<Creature> creatures = getCreatures();
    for (Creature c : creatures) {
        if (!(c instanceof PC) && !(c.getName().equals(name))) {
                c.reactStateChange(command, pc);
                c.checkNewRoom();
//                    if (!temp.equals(c)) {
//                        i--;
//                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how much shorter the code is without all of those getCreatures()[i] calls all over the place. I also dropped the null check, as it is redundant. instanceof already covers this.

**Edit** The reduced code also helps highlight a likely bug. The check for `!temp.equals(getCreatures()[i])` doesn't make sense because you are comparing the same objects always. I have no idea what your intention was in decrementing the loop index to revisit the previous node. Generally, it is very unusual to mess with the loop index like that in a for loop. With the enhanced for-loop, it is impossible; and that is very intentional.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Kris Kringle. It was a leftover cut and paste error from the original code. I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for fixing it.  However this introduced a new problem as I just kept my old code and had things working find, but I'm interested in learning better ways of doing things.   ConcurrentModificationException is the exception I get on the for loop.

Comment: Typically you get a ConcurrentModificationException when you try to modify a collection while you are iterating over it. If you are using the enhanced for loop, or an iterator to traverse a collection, you cannot modify that collection while doing so (unless you use the Iterator's API to perform the modification. I would need to see your new code to point out the problem exactly.

Answer (score 3):

- index access in a `List` - `list.get(idx)`
- `.length` is `.size()`
- index assignment is `list.set(idx, value)` (but you usually use `list.add(value)`)

That's about all you need to know to transition from an array to list.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
getCreatures()[i]
```

use

```
getCreatures().get(i)
```